# Default Roles - Discord.py Rewrite

Tags: python-3.7, discord.py

I am pretty new to Python, and I am coding a discord bot using discord.py rewrite, python 3.7. Lately I've been trying to set it up so it will assign a default role to any new members. From what I've gathered, the answer seems to be this:

```
@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    role = discord.utils.get(member.guild.roles, name = "Unverified")
    await member.add_roles(member, role)
```

I get the following error:

```
discord.errors.NotFound: NOT FOUND (status code: 404): Unknown Role
```

I have checked the spelling several times. "Unverified" definitely does exist on the server. I'm not sure what to do to fix the error. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to add the role `member` to `member`.  Just do

```
await member.add_roles(role)
```